# jQuery UI, how to get element id where drop the element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

my code is below:

when I drop li items in content div's span element, at time I want get span tag's id
how it possible?

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/AdEuz/)

```
<ul class="secd_line_icon" id="secd_line_icon" >
    <li id="products">
        <img id="productid_1" class="product" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1888289249/heart_sm_normal.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>


<ul id="bookmark_icon" class="droppable" style="height: 100px;">

</ul>

<div id="content" >
    <span id="s1">I have two hearts 
Heart is pulsating with blood <span>

<span id="s2"> And heart is pulsating with love 
        </span>
</div>

<script>
    $("#content").droppable({
        accept: '#secd_line_icon li',
        drop: function(event, ui) {

            $("#bookmark_icon").append($(ui.draggable).clone());
            $("#content_area .product").addClass("item");
            $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable product");
            $(".item").draggable({
                containment: 'parent',
                grid: [150,150]
            });
        }
    });
    $("#secd_line_icon li").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean the drop target element?

Comment: yes, where I can stop clicking mouse button...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the element that receive the drop by checking `event.target` in the [`drop event`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop).

The event and ui parameters contain some information about the drag and drop elements.

You can get the id of the element that receive the drop with: `$(event.target).attr('id')`

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Pf4P9/1/

Comment: The fiddle isn't working - 11/4/22.  Not clear what to drag or where to drop it either, but maybe if it was working it would be clearer.